# How to calculate discrepancy of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, matlab

For $d\geq1$ let $I^d=[0,1)^d$ denote the $d$-dimensional half-open unit cube and consider a finite sequence $x_1,\ldots,x_N\in{I}^d$. For a subset $J\subset{I}$, let $A(J,N)$ denote the number of elements of this sequence inside $J$, i.e.
$$
A(J,N)=\left|\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}\cap{J}\right|,
$$
and let $V(J)$ denote the volume of $J$. The *discrepenacy* of the sequence $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ is defined as
$$
D_N=\sup_{J}{\left|A(J,N)-V(J)\cdot{N}\right|},
$$
where the supremum is taken over all half-open subintervals $J=\prod_{j=1}^d{[0,t_j)}$, with $0\leq{t_j}\leq1$. The discrepancy thus compares the actual number of points in a given volume with the expected number of points in that volume, assuming the sequence $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ is uniformly distributed in $I^d$.

So far, so good. But say I want to calculate the discrepancy of a given sequence. Does anyone know how to? There are an infinite number of half-open subintervals $J$, making this (at least to me) non-trivial. Eventually I want to compare different low-discrepancy sequences in MATLAB, so if anyone knows a heuristic for this I am equally happy and grateful `:)`

Comment: You only need to check *around* finitely many points of type whose coordinates are drawn from respective coordinates of other points.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Got distracted by the _sup_. Now I only have to consider $N^2$ subsets $J$.

Comment: Not really. You have $N^d$ subsets of interest and possibly $2^d$ points to sample around each one. This is in the most dumbest approach possible. $N^2$ seems way too low - gotta depend on $d$ somehow.

Comment: Oh sorry, was focussing on the $2$-dimensional case, so $N^d=N^2$.

Comment: What does it mean for a finite sequence to be uniformly distributed?

Answer (score 2):

To compute discrepancy, we want to consider two types of sets $J$: ones that contain an unusually low number of points for their volume, and ones that contain an unusually high number of points for their volume.

For sets of the first type, if we can increase their volume without adding any additional points, we might as well do this. If $J = \prod_{j=1}^d [0,t_j)$, then we can increase each $t_j$ without any price to pay, until either $t_j = (x_i)_j$ for some $x_i \in \{x_1, \dots, x_N\}$, or else $t_j = 1$. So we might as well assume $J$ is already of this form: something like

[image: large volume]

There are $(N+1)^d$ sets to check like this: we just check all possibilities where $t_j \in \{(x_1)_j, \dots, (x_N)_j, 1\}$, for each $j$. (Note that this also wastes some checks: sometimes, we set $t_j = (x_i)_j$ even though $x_i$ is not on the boundary of $j$, because some other coordinate is too large.)

A similar thing happens for sets of the second type, except for weird interaction between their half-openness and the supremum. If $J =\prod_{j=1}^d [0,t_j)$, we want $t_j$ to be just a tiny bit greater than $(x_i)_j$ for some $x_i \in J$, so that $J$ includes $x_i$ without wasting too much volume.

Equivalently, we can just check sets of the form $J = \prod_{j=1}^d [0,t_j]$: closed subintervals. These are not elements of the set we're taking the supremum over, but they're limit points: each such set has discrepancy approximated by the discrepancies of $J_\epsilon = \prod_{j=1}^d [0,t_j+\epsilon)$, as $\epsilon \to 0$. Such sets $J$ look like:

[image: small volume]

Anyway, as before, there's only a finite number of cases to check here: we iterate over all $N^d$ possibilities where $t_j \in \{(x_1)_j, \dots, (x_N)_j\}$. These are almost exactly the same possibilities we considered in the first case, except now we include the points on the boundary when computing discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer and the diagrams! Two questions about this. 1) Are you saying that both cases should be checked or is the second case enough by itself?
2) Does it cause much inaccuracy in practice to always have one side of the rectangle at the origin instead of also moving around? It seems like it would be more technically correct to look at all N^2 regions for each point combination, but I'm not sure if that would give you a much better answer in practice?
It seems like most algorithms are to aproximate, so maybe this is good enough?
Thanks!

Comment: @AlanWolfe Both cases should be checked: they differ in whether we include the points on the boundary. (Although, for points in general position, we expect at most $d$ points on the boundary, which might not affect the answer too much.)

Comment: I used rectangles with one corner at the origin because that's the only kind of rectangle considered in the original question. But if you want discrepancy over all rectangles, then we can allow both sides to vary over coordinates used by some point, which gives us around $\binom N2^d$ cases to check but otherwise works in the same way